# Couldnt able remove space between navbar and landing page

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have created website using react, but when i added a navbar and home page under it - it's showing a space which am not able to remove.

[image]

Comment: What space? And what is your code look like?

Comment: need more information ==> sample code and which space exactly

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you clearly.

You could use `width:100%` in css of your nav bar.

Please refer:
https://www.impressivewebs.com/width-100-percent-css/

Answer (score 1):

in CSS you can put something like:

```
*{
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

and see which one takes extra space
OR:
[image]